# PyTorch installation error - KeyError `torch`

Tags: python, installation, pytorch, package

Context: I am attempting to install PyTorch in my virtual environment on VSCode. My OS is Xubuntu 21.10

Running the following command generated from the pytorch website:

```
pip3 install torch==1.10.1+cpu torchvision==0.11.2+cpu torchaudio==0.10.1+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch_stable.html
```

produces the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/resolvelib-0.5.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 171, in _merge_into_criterion
    crit = self.state.criteria[name]
KeyError: 'torch'
```

I also received the following error in addition to the above keyerror:

```
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

I could only find a similar issue generated by someone calling `pytorch` instead of `torch`, but nothing about `torch` throwing a keyerror. I tried pasting it and also typing it out manually to ensure there was no hidden whitespace or characters, but the same issue was generated. What avenues can I explore to solve this issue?

Comment: did you find a solution? I dont get connection reset, I get a file not found error

Comment: I was never able to solve this @Seeker, I've been using TensorFlow instead